# Extract ID from Tapestry URLs

Tags: tapestry

I have a tapestry url that looks like

```
http://localhost:8888/forwardtask/88
```

how do i get the 88 bit? thanks. Tapestry is such a pain to use

Comment: There are plenty alternatives to Tapestry, you know, and most of them are easier to use

Comment: i'm inheriting some other guy's code and i'm not really a java guru

Comment: Hmm... you generally need at least 2 brains to deal with Tapestry, and at least one of them has to Java well to handle Tapestry's baroque complexity.

Comment: amen on baroque. going from Django to Tapestry made me want to slice my wrists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [page navigation section in the Tapestry 5 docs](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.1/guide/pagenav.html), particularly Page Activation.

Effectively, you'll want this in your page class:

```
void onActivate(long forwardTaskId) {
    ...
}
```

This bit will execute before the page renders if there is a parameter in the URL.

Tapestry has some non-obvious concepts that you'll have to understand to be effective, but it's not rocket science. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a newer version 5.1 Tapestry  you can just create a variable like:

```
@PageActivationContext
int myNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

typically (althought I dont know all the cases) paths in Tapestry are defined by OnActivate and onPassivate and they are generated by event context clicks (pagelink,actionlink,eventlink). check the context elements in the .tml your coming from and then look at the Active and Passive methods on the page your going to.